# Avro - how to switch encoding from binary to JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, avro

I am starting with avro following some "getting started" examples and in avro manual I found:

> Avro specifies two serialization encodings: binary and JSON. Most applications will use the binary encoding, as it is smaller and faster. But, for debugging and web-based applications, the JSON encoding may sometimes be appropriate.

But I can't find nether a method on java API nor an example how to perform this switch. Does anyone have an idea?

My expectation was on DatumWriter, DataFileWriter or on generated classes as manual states serialization happens in in memory while building the object.

Can anyone clarify?

Thx